# Cassandra vs MongoDB in respect of Secondary Index?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, cassandra

At [blog](https://scalegrid.io/blog/cassandra-vs-mongodb/) I see below statement

> Secondary indexes are a first-class construct in MongoDB. This makes
>   it easy to index any property of an object stored in MongoDB even if
>   it is nested. This makes it really easy to query based on these
>   secondary indexes. Cassandra has only cursory support for secondary
>   indexes. Secondary indexes are also limited to single columns and
>   equality comparisons.

I have two related questions on it .

> > Cassandra has only cursory support for secondary indexes.

Not sure what makes Mongo to have better support than cassandra which just has cursory support ?

> > Secondary indexes[Cassandra] are also limited to single columns

My understanding on above statement is that cassandra supports secondary indexes only on single column not on composite column

> > Secondary indexes[Cassandra] are also limited to equality comparisons.
> >      I believe it means Mongo can use index for greater/lass than operation also but cassandra is limited to equality ?

My understanding is Mongo implements the secondar index in similar fashion as RDBMS but not sure how cassandra implements it at high level ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The major difference between Mongo & Cassandra is that, Mongo is mater/slave DB Vs Cassandra is a masterless system.

Having said that, all writes happen to a single PRIMARY node in Mongo which gets replicated to SECONDARIES. So the entire data is available in a single node and hence having a secondary index & querying by it becomes simpler (just like any other RDBMS). Hence it supports all types of queries against a secondary index. It gets complicated as we move towards a Mongo Sharded system vs a simple replicaset.

In case of Cassandra, the data is distributed into multiple nodes based on the partition key. Now building a secondary index is only relative to data on that particular node and is unaware about the data in other nodes. So querying for a column in secondary index results in scatter gather, because the matching data could lie in any node. As no partitioning key is involved to restrict number of nodes, this type of query would be very slow (depending on the cluster size).

So having a RANGE query in Mongo is no big deal, because the entire data is available in PRIMARY node. While Cassandra the range scan of secondary index would mean scanning every row in that given node. So a range query can take forever and hence not supported.

Comment: JFYI, mongo database also can be sharded and _still_ can do all kinds of queries against a secondary index.

Comment: It can do vs how well it will perform varies a lot on the size of data, no. of shards and complexity of query being performed. The moment we ask for queries on non shard keys, we are doing scatter gather and asking for trouble.

Comment: Agreed, scatter-gather is best avoided. Although when queries hit the shards, they enjoy the usual benefits of indexes. It's just the merge stage afterwards that adds a bit of slowdown. Btw, if my memory serves me, mongo won't let you run a query against a sharded collection without a shard key in it. So that's a bit of help.

Comment: There are specific type of queries like aggregate that can’t be performed on a sharded collection. But it allows generic queries on non sharded columns as well. It’s just going to be on slower side.

Comment: @dilsingi As you said `In case of Cassandra, the data is distributed into multiple nodes based on the partition key.` Can't we have  `simple replicaset instead of shard/partition`
under cassandra like in Mongo ? Is it mandatory to have partition based on some key in cassandra ? Also what i understand is that mongo will face the similar issue(scatter and gather) once we have shards ?

Comment: @emilly there is no concept of primary/slave in Cassandra and it’s designed as a masterless active/active system. In CAP theorem Cassandra falls under AP with tunable consistency and Mongo under CP. in general any distributed database scales horizontally with partition key and has to be thoughtful about their data models. So yes, Mongo secondary indexes will be scatter gather queries once sharded.

Comment: @dilsingi can not we have all data on one node in cassandra and then replicate the same data in some secondary node for failover ? For example  if I have electronics and  food as product types, in mongo(just for high availability , without shards) I can keep all data(both prod types) on master and same will be replicated on slave . Can not I do the same thing on cassandra too  ?

Comment: @emily It isn't the way Cassandra works. Please read the following Cassandra architecture reference https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/architecture/archIntro.html

Comment: @dilsingi Read the link. My question is simple  :- Lets say I want to use cassandra where I want to store all the data on one node(where all all request goes to this) and use another replica node for failobver/backup ?How can i model this usecase in cassandra ?

Comment: @emily Then have a single node Cassandra cluster or have a single partition key so that all data resides in same node. But honestly no point in using Cassandra for this use case.

Comment: Ok. But how will use another node for replication so that if first node is fail/crashed, second node becomes main node

Comment: Okays open up a new question with details on what your intended use case, I believe I have answered this question related to indexes. Also remember to accept answers.