# Replication without partitioning in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, nosql

In Mongo we can  go for  any of the below model

1. Simple replication(without shard where one node will be working as master and other as slaves) or
2. Shard(where data will be distributed on different shard based on partition key)
3. Both 1 and 2

My question - Can't we have Cassandra just with replication without partitioning just like model_1 in mongo ?

From [Cassandra vs MongoDB in respect of Secondary Index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48267822/cassandra-vs-mongodb-in-respect-of-secondary-index)

In case of Cassandra, the data is distributed into multiple nodes based on the partition key.

From above it looks like it is mandatory to distribute the data based on some p[artition key when we have more than one node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cassandra, replication factor defines how many copies of data you have. Partition key is responsible for distributing of data between nodes.  But this distribution may depend on the amount of nodes that you have. For example, if you have 3 nodes cluster & replication factor equal to 3, then all nodes will get data anyway...

Comment: Is it possible to have just   replication without partitioning the data in cassandra i.e model_1 in my question ?

Comment: If you have RF equal to number of machines, then all machines will have copy of data... But take into account that in Cassandra, there is no slaves & masters - all nodes are equal...

Comment: One quick question is I have 3 nodes and  RF is 2  with some partitioning key. Is this the router who decided which node contain appropriate data based on partition key ?

Comment: it's called the coordination node - it performs hashing of partition key to find node(s) that are responsible for handling of the this range of hash values... https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-arch/datastax_enterprise/dbArch/archDataDistributeTOC.html of Architecture guide contains all necessary information (the whole guide is short, but contains a lot of useful information)

Comment: say I have 3 sharded nodes i.e. N1,N2,N3 storing the ecommerce data with product type as partition key. N1 stores garments, N2 stores electronics and N3 stores shoes. Say I have replication factor as 3. My understanding is I need 3 more nodes to to have replica. These 3 nodes will be different from sharded nodes. Is n't it ? Or Sharded nodes will also work as replica nodes ? If yes then sharded nodes contains all the data and no more stores the data based on product type and defeats the purpose ?

Comment: Not really. If you have 3 nodes & RF=3, then every node will have a full copy of all data, but only one node is "primary replica" (https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ArchitectureInternals) - but this is just an internal stuff, every replica is able to serve read & write requests... As you add nodes, the replicas will be rebalanced to accommodate the available resources.  Also, product type isn't very good candidate for partition key - in this case it will contain all data with it, and this could lead to imbalanced data distribution, and performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your intuition is right: The data is always distributed based on the partition key. The partition key is also called row key or primary key, so you can see: you have one anyway. The 1. case of your mongo example is not doable in cassandra, mainly because cassandra does not know the concept of masters and slaves. If you have a 2 node cluster and a replication factor of 2, then the data will be held on 2 nodes, like [Alex Ott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18627/alex-ott) already pointed out. When you query (read or write), your client will decide to which to connect and perform the operation. To my knowledge, the default here would be a round robin load balancing between the two nodes, so either of them will receive somewhat the same load. If you have 3 nodes and a replication factor of 2, it becomes a little more tricky. The nice part is though, that you can determine the set of nodes which hold your data in the client code, thus you don't lose any performance by connecting to a "wrong" node.

One more thing about partitions: you can configure some of this, but this would be per server and not per table. I've never used this, and personally i wouldn't recommend to do so. Just stick to the default mechanism of cassandra.

And one word about the secondary index thing. Use materialized [views](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/understanding-materialized-views)

Comment: One word about materialized views. DON'T USE THEM! :-) In fact, they were put back into experimental because they are not production ready.

Comment: "The partition key is also called row key or primary key" -> This is not true all the times. If you have clustering columns, the partition key is different from the "row key" or "primary key".

Comment: Then probably don't use both, because of the performance impact of secondary indices and the instability of views.